# Incomplete number of observations in an hourly time sequence

Tags: r, time

I am trying to generate a list of hourly time from Dec 1, 2016 to Jun 30, 2017 as follows:

```
time_index <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2016-12-01 01:00", tz = 'UTC'), to = as.POSIXct("2017-06-30 00:00", tz = 'UTC'), by = "hour")
```

There should be 5088 items (212 days x 24 hours). However, it is only generating 5064 items.

```
> length(time_index)
[1] 5064
```

How to generate total 5088 items? Is it due to day light saving time?

Thanks

Comment: First of all you're excluding all the hours >= 1:00 of the last day, and also the 0:00 of the first day. You should use : `seq(from=as.POSIXct("2016-12-01 00:00", tz='UTC'), to=as.POSIXct("2017-06-30 23:00", tz='UTC'), by="hour")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have found my mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code. I have missed the proper range before.

```
time_index <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2016-12-01 01:00", tz='UTC'), to=as.POSIXct("2017-06-30 24:00", tz='UTC'), by="hour")
```

Comment: Are you sure ? The last value of time_index is `2017-07-01 00:00:00 UTC`...